# Trying to add ezartech plugin to my project

Tags: node.js, cordova

i'm trying to add ezartech plugin to my project (ezartech videoOverlay)
Now... my friend said, i should add the plugin with command.
So i went ahead, and tried to add it with command, my command looks like this.

```
C:\Users\Mikk\Desktop\reality\myAwesomeApp>cordova plugin add c:/users/mikk/desktop/plugins/com.ezartech.ezar.videooverlay
```

But it returns me error: Invalid plugin! C:\Users\Mikk\Desktop\plugins\com.ezartech.ezar.videooverlay needs a valid package.json

Is there any workaround within this?

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem, which got resolved only when downgraded my Cordova version.
With version 6.5.0 it doesn't require any package.json/package.json.lock file.
So, you can remove/uninstall current installed npm cordova from global path and install $ npm install cordova@6.5.0 -g

Comment: ezAr has published the updated plugin, compatible with 7.0.1, see: https://www.ezartech.com/forum/?p=%3Fforum%3D612227